# Merge Statement with two inserts?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given is a simple MERGE statement. Where I Insert/Update records into traget table. Question: is it possible to also Insert those values in another table with a flag beeing 0 for insert and 1 for update? Eg. when not match do insert into target and another table, when matched do update target and insert into another table.

```
MERGE dbo.FactBuyingHabits AS Target
USING (SELECT CustomerID, ProductID, PurchaseDate FROM dbo.Purchases) AS Source
  ON (Target.ProductID = Source.ProductID AND Target.CustomerID = Source.CustomerID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET Target.LastPurchaseDate = Source.PurchaseDate
  --and insert into test_tbl values (1, Source.ProductID, Source.CustomerID) --?
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  INSERT (CustomerID, ProductID, LastPurchaseDate)
  VALUES (Source.CustomerID, Source.ProductID, Source.PurchaseDate)
  --and insert into test_tbl values (0, Source.ProductID, Source.CustomerID) --?
```

Comment: you could create a trigger on the target table to handle the 'logging'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should read about [OUTPUT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

ex ([source](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/implementing-the-output-clause-in-sql-server-2008/));

```
DECLARE @MergeOutput1 table
(
  ActionType nvarchar(10),
  BookID int,
  OldBookTitle nvarchar(50),
  NewBookTitle nvarchar(50),
  ModifiedDate datetime
);

-- use MERGE statement to perform update on Book2

MERGE Books2 AS b2
USING Books AS b1
ON (b2.BookID = b1.BookID)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN UPDATE
SET b2.BookTitle = b1.BookTitle
OUTPUT
    $action,
    INSERTED.BookID,
    DELETED.BookTitle,
    INSERTED.BookTitle,
    INSERTED.ModifiedDate
  INTO @MergeOutput1;
```